# Mandelbrot set won't accelerate using pthread

Tags: c++, pthreads, mandelbrot

So, I'm writing a program to compute the Mandelbrot set using pthread. 
This is the thread function:

```
void *partial_compute(void *arg) {
    cout << "enter" << flush;
    Range *range = (Range*)arg;
    Comp z, c;
    for (int i = range->begin; i <= range->end; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y_length; j++) {
            z.set(0.0, 0.0);
            c.set(x_start + (x_end - x_start) * i / x_length, y_start + (y_end - y_start) * j / y_length);
            int k;
            for (k = 0; k < 256; k++) {
                z = z.next(c);
                if (z.length() >= 4.0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            *(canvas + i * y_length + j) = k;
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Which `Comp` is a class of complex number, and `z.next` means computing the next Mandelbrot iteration.

```
Comp Comp::next(Comp c) {
    Comp n(next_real(c), next_imag(c));
    return n;
}
float Comp::next_real(Comp c) {
    return _real * _real - _imag * _imag + c.real();
}
float Comp::next_imag(Comp c) {
    return 2 * _real * _imag + c.imag();
}
```

I set a pair of `clock_t` before `pthread_create` and after `pthread_join`. 
The result of the Mandelbrot set is correct, however, the computing time is always the same despite I increased the number of threads from 1 to 8. 
Because the `"enter"` were printed out at the same time a second before `pthread_join`, I believe the threads were executed parallelly. 
I guess the problem may be that there is the thread-safe function in `partial_compute`, but I can't find it. (I've try to represent the complex number by the `float` instead of class) 
Is there any mistake I made here? Thank for your help.

**Update:** 
Sorry for the incomplete information. 
`z.length()` means the square of the complex number z. 
This is how I split the task. `x_length` and `y_length` means the width and the height of the screen. 
I split the screen to n part by width, and send the range to the thread to compute.

```
int partial_length = x_length / num_threads;
for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
    range[i].begin = i * partial_length;
    range[i].end = range[i].begin + partial_length - 1;
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, partial_compute, (void *)&range[i]);
}
// wait all the threads finished
for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
}
```

Comment: What processor (how many cores)? What does `z.length()` do?

Comment: Can you show us how you split up the set to compute between the threads, i.e. which thread is computing which part of the total set?

Comment: Put the code which start the threads too...

Comment: Perhaps the code is limited by memory access speed and not by the speed of your computations?

Comment: Ok, now number of threads you're starting? Number of cores you have on that machine? How long is the calculation running for?

Comment: The simplest explanation is that your clock() function just doesn't have enough resolution to be able to show the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem is the `clock()`...... 
The `clock()` cannot be used to measure the elapsed time when you use pthread, 
hence I found `gettimeofday(timeval, NULL)` can work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a problem with `clock()` in Pthreads. You can use `clock_gettime()` with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` option, to measure the time correctly in Pthreads. You will also need to link against the POSIX Realtime extensions (-lrt) for this.

Here is an examples:

```
struct timespec begin, end;
double elapsed;

clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &begin);

// spawn threads to do work here

clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);

elapsed = end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec;
elapsed += (end.tv_nsec - begin.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
```